# Excel: Search A Cell To See If A Cell From An Entire Column Is Present

Tags: excel

Having trouble with a formula to solve this problem. I can do it when comparing one cell but can't figure out how to do it to check the entire column.

What I have two columns.  Column A is a list of keywords.  Column B is a list of Cities.

I want to compare all of Column B to see if any of those cities are contained on a cell by cell basis in column a

If I just use    `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,A2))`    it will compare all the cells in column A to B2 and the formula works.  But I have a few hundred cells in Column B that I want to compare A2 too.  I want to know if any of the words in Column B show up in the cell A2

Instead of just `$B$1` I'd like to compare the entire B column **(Like B:B but that doesn't work)** and see if any of the words in Column B are in Cell A2.

[image]

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: [http://www.vzpro.com/wp-content/uploads/example-data.png

Comment: Sorry.  First time posting.  Forgot to open the cell so you could see all data in it.  My apologies.  [http://www.vzpro.com/wp-content/uploads/example-data.png

Comment: are you doing this one time, or over and over again? + do you care to know in which cell from A the city name is present, or just the presence in general?

Comment: Over and Over again meaning I want each of the cells in column B to be checked to see if it's in cell A2, Then I want to check to see if any of the cells in Column B are in Cell A3, etc etc.  And the list is much longer than the data I shared.  I'll eventually want to do this with different data sets and just change out Column A each time.

Comment: The reason I ask is that you could `CONCATENATE` your column and search on that (assuming size is ok). It wouldn't tell you which City it found but it would tell you that *a* city has been found. Because concatenating a range involves some manual work, this isn't the most scalable of methods..

Comment: My goal here is eventually to filter all the phases in Column A THAT HAVE one of the items from column B.  So I don't care if to know what word it has, just that it has one.

Comment: Greener, I'll try that real quick.  Not sure how that function would work to join them.  =CONCAT(?

Answer (score 0):

Using the whole column `B:B` is not possible because of performance issues. But you could using a part of the column `$B$2:$B$100` within an array formula.

Example:

[image]

Formula in English notation:

```
{=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$67,A2)))}
```

This is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. The curly brackets will then appear automatically.

How it works:

In array context `ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$67,A2))` takes all values of `$B$2:$B$67` into the formula and results in an array of `{TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, ...}` dependent of whether the value is found in `A2` or not. The `--` gets the boolean values as numeric 0 or 1.  The `SUM` then sums the array. So it counts how often 1 will be present.

---

Edit:

This needs the `$B$2:$B$67` filled with values because otherwise the `""` from empty cells will always be found. So to be more flexible we should check whether cells in `$B$2:$B$1000` are empty and excluding those then.

```
{=SUM(($B$2:$B$1000<>"")*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$1000,A2)))}
```

Comment: Yes, this formula worked.  Is there a limit to the amount of size to the array that you can think of?

Comment: Depends on your hardware, especially the number of processors available and the `RAM` memory size. But up to 1000 rows in column B should be not a problem.

Comment: Just an FYI just did a 30k x 30k array using the formula and it took about 2 minutes but ran perfectly.